# Are there any detriments to calling logic code from Dispose in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

### A Bit of Background

For example, say there is a Blazor page that tracks when a person looks at the page and updates a `DateTime` value for the sake of knowing when the page was last viewed.

I want to track when that users *leaves* the page and update that last viewed value to when the user leaves and not when the user first joins.

From what I have seen, I could do something using the `NavigationManager` and the events it contains to track when the URL changes and know that the user has left the page based upon that, but that seems overly complicated where there seems to be an easier solution.

### The Question

If I have a Blazor page that implements `IDisposable` simillarly to the following:

```cs
public partial class RazorPage : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposedValue;

    // ...

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                TriggerNotificationUpdate();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private TriggerNotificationUpdate()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And where `TriggerNotificationUpdate()` calls a scoped service that has been injected with Dependency Injection in the following way:

```cs
private TriggerNotificationUpdate()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () => {
        await _service.UpdateTimestamp();
    });
}
```

**Is there any detriments, or major reasons why I should not be using this type of logic in my code?**

Comment: Yes pretty bad idea. `Dispose` should never ever ever throw an exception and should complete almost instantly, because can sometimes be run from the finalizer thread

Comment: Iirc, using `Task.Run(async () => { ... });` (and not saving the task to a variable) will swallow exceptions and complete very quickly, as its not waiting on any code to execute. That *technically* meets your requirements @Charlieface - but I'm gonna guess its still a bad idea :)

Comment: Hum, you're right, didn't realize it was a `Task.Run`. But I would still do `try { await _service.UpdateTimestamp(); } catch { }` because it's more explicit

Comment: Will do, thanks for the comments.

Comment: The SuppressFinalize() is not called for, there is no destructor here and you could interfere with the base class.

Comment: On the whole it looks like it might work (server-side). On Wasm I would not be so sure.

Comment: Note that you can eliminate a lambda: `_ = Task.Run(_service.UpdateTimestamp);` is OK.

Comment: Track the navigation event, leave `Dispose` for disposing.  Use a service which registers a delegate on the NavigationManager navigate event and make you decisions from there.  It's what the `Router` does.  The right decision isn't necessarily the easiest!

Comment: Very true. I wound up just handling last view times on pagination events, as someone may not look all the way to the end (and then they would still have notifications to view).

Comment: Suggestion: have an injected service with a queue of items to update. When you dispose, make a quick call to the service to push the requested update onto the queue. Then the service can perform background async dequeuing and make the updates without blocking the Dispose call.